# How to pass the keystore to the JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to connect with the oracle databases. I've created the small project, that the connection works fine.

```
public void makeCon() {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS) (HOST =example.com) (PORT = 8080))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = somesid)))";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "username");
        props.setProperty("password", "pass");
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\src\\main\\resources\\local.keystore");
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "secretpassword");
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This connection works fine, I was able to do some query. Right now I would like to connect on my main project. I've there connection that based on application properties, and everything works fine, but right now when I want to change the database that will connect with SSO oracle, that does not work.

```
 @Bean(name = "sql")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "sqlDataNamed")
  public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(DataSource pricingDataSource) {
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
    template.setFetchSize(500);
      return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(template);
  }
```

I've tried to add this keystore to the JdbcTemplate or to the Datasource somehow, but I couldnt do it. The documentation does not show how to put the properties. System.setProperties does not work, after that there is an error:

```
Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Thanks in advice

Comment: Try : `Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(“trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl”, “path_to_truststore_file”);
properties.put(“trustCertificateKeyStorePassword”, “mypassword”);`

Comment: @VinayHegde and where I should use this properties?

Comment: @VinayHegde What is your source for this suggestion?

Comment: But I have use it and that true - I am able to connect with the DB, but in my project I dont know how to use it, so my question was where I should use this, and "during conection" is not telling me much :(